# Numpy - generating a sequence with a higher resolution within certain bounds

Tags: python, numpy

Generating a sequence of a range with evenly spaced points using Numpy is accomplished easily using [`np.linspace(a, c, n)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) where `a` is the start of the range, `c` is the endpoint of the range and `n` are the number of evenly spaced intervals.

I am interested to know if there is any similar function which allows a finer resolution for a subset of the range e.g. `[a,b]` where `a<b<c`. At the moment i am using:

`np.append(np.linspace(a, b, n), np.linspace(b, c, n))`

which does the trick but is there a Numpy implementation already specifically for this or perhaps a smarter way to do this?

Comment: I'm not aware of one, but with your current approach `b` will appear twice, as `np.linspace` output includes both end points (which is different than `np.arange` which only includes the left end point)

Comment: @BradCampbell To fix that, one can use the argument `endpoint=False`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could construct such a sequence by first making an array containing the spacings between each pair of points, then taking a cumsum over this.

For example, let's suppose I want to go from 0 to 50 everywhere in steps of 1, except between 20 and 30 where I want steps of 0.25:

```
import numpy as np

deltas = np.repeat([0, 1, 0.25, 1], [1, 20, 40, 20])
pts = np.cumsum(deltas)
```

Plotting:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.eventplot(pts)
ax.margins(x=0.05)
```

[image]

---

#### Edit

I'd totally forgotten about [`np.r_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html), which offers a very nice compact way to achieve the same thing:

```
pts2 = np.r_[0:20:1, 20:30:0.25, 30:51:1]
```

As well as specifying a step size manually, you can also use an imaginary number as the step size, which is equivalent to using `np.linspace` to specifying the number of steps to take, e.g. `np.r_[0:10:20j]` is the same as `np.linspace(0, 10, 20)`.

Comment: Your use of `np.r_` is exactly what i am looking for! Thx!